# Which document scanners work with Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, scanner

I'm searching for a scanner which helps me to turn my invoces and other random papers into pdfs. I need Linux support because I do not own a Windows/Linux device and using a virtual machine is not a solution.

A automated document feeder (ADF) is necessary. Whether the device consists only of a ADF or is a combination of a ADF with a flatbed is not that important, I would go for the second solution if I have the choice.

I thought about the [Canonc P-215](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/office/products/hardware/scanners/high_speed_document_scanners/imageformula_p_215_scan_tini_personal_document_scanner), but I was not able to check its Linux support. The [SANE device list](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON) does not mention this scanner.

Comment: Canon has a bad linux compatibility record for scanners.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use almost any printer that has a USB interface... USB would be on the front, not the output to PC connections. Look for Scan to USB, or Scan to Thumbdrive. All versions of Ubuntu, I have used, will recognize the thumbdrive on the Networked or Installed Printer. So you would need to use the internal scan functions on the printer.  This capability is found often in Multi-Function all in one Printers. If you use grayscale, and PDF for the scan and save config, often times the ADF will run quicker then Neatdesk. The problem being that integrated ADFs tend to start scanning crooked early on, so repairs and tunes ups occur quite frequently.  "This is from personal experience" :D Hope you found this helpful.

Comment: This is pretty brilliant answer. I never occurred to me the my multi-function printer could handle all the heavy lifting. But I just tried it an it worked like a charm. Thank you! (Now I just need to figure out how to adjust the resulting documents crookedness and how to handle OCR in batch.)

Answer (score 1):

HP has excellent Linux support, see HP's site [here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/about.html).

Comment: HPs most recent ScanJets are not supported by hplib and the sane project. They use a generic chip which is (currently) unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Canon P-215 you mentioned. I got it in 2013 because of the high recommendation it received on theWireCuttr. Sadly, I wasn't able to get it to work on Linux.

However, Canon have released Linux drivers (release date February 4th 2015) which can be found here: [Linux Drivers](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/scanners/others/p-215.aspx?type=download&language=EN&os=Linux).

The driver page states that the drivers have support for the following Linux Distributions:

- Ubuntu: 12.10, 13.04, 13.10, 14.04
- Debian: 6.0, 7.0
- Fedora: 17, 18, 19, 20
- OpenSUSE: 12.2, 12.3, 13.1